# Minimization problem using PMP

Tags: optimization

---

**Problem:**

I have to give the minima, subject to $x'(t) = u(t)$, $x(0) = 0$ and $x(1) = 1$ of the following function:

$\int_0^1 u(t) dt$

I have to find this minima using the Pontryagin's Maximum Principle.

---

**What we have so far:**

- $H = pu- \lambda_0 u$
- $x'  = \hat{H_p}=u$
- $p' =0$
- $p-\lambda_0=0 \iff p=\lambda_0$

Exclude bad case: if $\lambda_0=0 \iff p=0$, and this cannot happen, since they cannot both be zero. So we choose $\lambda_0=1$

$H_u=p-1$, Since $p=\lambda_0=1, H_u=0$

---

Can anyone please help us!